# Gradle DSL method not found : testCompile()

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, android-testing

I am using gradle version - `3.3-all` and gradle plugin - `gradle:2.3.3`
I want to write test cases. So as per this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#build), I included the following in the the app's top `build.gradle` file.

```
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

But I get the error saying

```
Error:(11, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'testCompile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'TopLevelProject' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Answer (score 0):

In gradle the configurations: `compile` `runtime` `testCompile` etc are coming from `java` plugin

But in android i think you need `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

**Edit:** Please share your root `build.gradle` and app `build.gradle` especially `android` closure, dependencies and plugins and describe which is where.

Sometimes is a structural problem and app related stuff lands in root `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so I post this as an answer.

I had a similar problem, try applying the Java plugin and the testCompiles in the app's build file, that is in: **project/app/build.gradle**, not the project's build file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
   ...
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```